# Copying point features along line features by predetermined distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, distance, python-parser

I have points in a feature class. Each point has its centroid on a unique line feature in a polyline feature class ( 62 points / 62 lines). Furthermore, points and their corresponding lines share unique identifiers in each of their attribute tables. My aim is create a new point feature along each of these lines at a distance (from old point to new point) also determined by a field in the line attributes.

Does this need to be scripted with python or is there a tool I can use?

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: Most GIS programs have Linear Referencing tools which will create Events along a route.  In ArcGIS, I suggest you have a look at the Linear Referencing toolbox.  There are plenty of posts on this site relating to similar tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% agree with @Fetzer, this is LR task, can be bulky though. Try this field calculator expression to find X of new point.

```
def getXY (point, id, d2add):
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
 lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"LINES")[0]
 q='"ITEMID"=%s%s%s' %(r"'",id,"'")
 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,"Shape@",q) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:line=row[0];break
 pointPos=line.measureOnLine((point)+d2add
 pNew=line.positionAlongLine(pointPos).firstPoint
 return pNew.X
```

To call it use:

```
getXY ( !Shape!, !ITEMID!, !CHAINAGE!)
```

where CHAINAGE field name storing distance to add. It requires a bit of adjustment using your field naming. Code assumes that lines layer called LINES in your table of content. Expression to be run on new field, type double. Change last line to get Y.

Tested on shapefile.

Comment: I always like your answers.  I had forgotten about the measureOnLine and positionAlongLine methods.

Comment: Would the "LINES" feature need to a be a route before running this script?

Comment: No. Just a layer with source in shapefile with id field type text. The simplest way to implement this is create new fields in point and line layers, call them ITEMID and populate with original IDs, using field calculator. in this case you don't have to modify expression at all

Comment: @Fezter thank you. Possibly it's because I have similar characters in my surname:) Well this 2 methods are my favourites, they easily replace LR when dealing with point events. Took ages for ESRI to resurrect them in ArcGIS after ArcView 3

Comment: Is there any language in the script that references the point layer name as seen in the table of contents? Also, what is "Shape@" and !Shape! referring to?

Comment: It is field calculator expression to be run on new numeric field called X. Language in script? what are you talking about? Just copy it in expression box, period

Comment: Did you do what I advised yesterday in regards of adding fields? If yes, there is 1 minor thing. Add field CHAINAGE to your points layer and populate it by shift values from whatever field is storing them. No modification will be required for expression at all

Comment: Yes I've added ITEMID fields to point and line layers, each having corresponding values. I added "CHAINAGE" to point layer and populated it with distance values also stored in point layer. I've copied and pasted the two scripts above in the "New_X" field with the "python" and "Number" radio buttons selected at the top of the field calculator windows. I receive a 000539 error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line1). Sorry for my struggling here, but I'm quite new to python

Comment: You have to set language to Python, see parcer on the top. Also check show codeblock thing. Expression goes into first box, single line goes into second textbox. Forget about radio button, it doesn't matter

Comment: New error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'geoprocessing describe geometry object' and 'float'. Before I added a parenthesis after line 7, I got a sytax error

Comment: pointPos=line.measureOnLine(point)+d2add