# Calculating chainage distance of points along polyline from start point of line using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, linear-referencing

I have road network polylines data with chainages at some specific points along the line.

Is there any way to calculate the chainage distance of each points from starting point of the polyline?

Comment: Return pointPos in this expression https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400955/extending-points-upstream-to-create-stream-reach-using-arcgis-pro/400967#400967

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

check this. Hope it will help.
https://github.com/ImranAhsan15/Chainage-creation-using-arcpy

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255905)